# validating decimals inputs in JSF

Tags: validation, jsf

I want to validate an input as an integer. Thus, any value with decimal fractions should be filtered. But I don't know how to achieve that. I have tried many things, but with the code below, if the input is "61.2", the value is converted to 61, just truncating decimal part. But I want to force a validation error. I am sure I can do it without a custom validator. Thanks

```
<p:inputText size="5" value="#{bean.intValue}"  converter="#{Integer}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" integerOnly="true" maxFractionDigits="0"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 12):

That's not possible as validation runs after conversion. You'd basically need to bind it to a `String` property instead of an `Integer` one in order to validate the unconverted value. You'd need to convert it afterwards in the property setter or the managed bean action method. So, if you make it a `String` property, you could use [`<f:validateRegex>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/validateRegex.html) for this.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" validatorMessage="Please enter digits only">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="\d*" />
</h:inputText>
```

Alternatively, and IMO better than manually converting it in the setter or action method, you could bring in a custom converter which extends the JSF standard [`IntegerConverter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/IntegerConverter.html) and validate the pattern in there right before conversion takes place.

```
@FacesConverter("digitsOnly")
public class DigitsOnlyConverter extends IntegerConverter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) throws ConverterException {
        if (!value.matches("\\d*")) {
            throw new ConverterException();
        }

        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    }

}
```

with

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" converterMessage="Please enter digits only">
    <f:converter converterId="digitsOnly" />
<h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

place minFractionDigits = "0" and pattern=" # # #"