# validating and displaying decimal numbers in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf

I wonder how to validate an inputText text field and see if it matchs a decimal format.
And also in the rendering time how to format that text field with a specific format

I've done this :

```
    <rich:column id="soldes_comptables">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Solde Comptable" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:inputText id="inputTextSC" value="#{file.soldes_comptables}"
                    label="Montant"
                    style="border-color:#F2F3F7;"
                    validatorMessage="The number must be decimal eg: 000.00"
                    >
                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###,##0.00"/>
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"></f:validateRegex>
                    <rich:validator />
                </h:inputText>
                <rich:message for="inputTextSC"/>
            </rich:column>
```

but it's not working as i want :(. please help me

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing validation and conversion. The `<f:validateRegex>` applies only on `String` values, not on `Number` values, however, the `<f:convertNumber>` has already converted it from `String` to `Number` beforehand, so the `<f:validateRegex>` is rather useless to you. You should remove it and specify the message as `converterMessage` instead.

```
<h:inputText ... converterMessage="The number must be decimal eg: 000.00">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###,##0.00"/>
</h:inputText>
```

An alternative would be to create a custom converter extending `NumberConverter` and throw a `ConverterException` on improper input format based on some regex pattern matching.

#### See also:

- [validating decimals inputs in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498617/validating-decimals-inputs-in-jsf)
- [How validate number fields with validateRegex in a JSF-Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501845/how-validate-number-fields-with-validateregex-in-a-jsf-page)